# ¿Cómo obtener los indices no cruzados de dos dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Es decir, teniendo dos *dataframes* me gustaría tener una salida con los registros cruzados (`df1.join (df2, how='inner'`) y otro con los no cruzados.  ¿Hay un método directo para esto?

Como ejemplo tenemos los siguientes dfs:

```
a = pd.DataFrame ({'A' :[3, 5], 'B': [8, 2]},
                  columns=['A','B'],
                  index=['T1','T2']
                  )
b = pd.DataFrame ({'C': [3, 5], 'D': [8, 2]},
                  columns=['C','D'],
                  index=['T1', 'T3']
                  )
```

obtengo solo los registros comunes (claves cruzadas: ***T1***):

```
a.join(b, how='inner')
```

obtengo todos los registros (claves cruzadas y no cruzadas: ***T1***, ***T2***, ***T3***):

```
a.join(b, how='outer')
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener los no cruzados (***T2*** y ***T3***)?

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es la diferencia simétrica de dos conjuntos, no puedes hacerlo de forma directa con `join` pero puedes usar el modo `"outher"` y luego usar [`pandas.Index.symmetric_difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.symmetric_difference.html) para realizar un filtro vía `loc`:

> ```
> >>> import pandas as pd
>
> >>> a = pd.DataFrame ({'A' :[3, 5], 'B': [8, 2]},
>                   columns=['A','B'],
>                   index=['T1','T2']
>                   )
>
> >>> b = pd.DataFrame ({'C': [3, 5], 'D': [8, 2]},
>                   columns=['C','D'],
>                   index=['T1', 'T3']
>                   )
>
> >>> a.index ^ b.index
> Index(['T2', 'T3'], dtype='object')
>
>
> >>> a.join(b, how='inner')
>     A  B  C  D
> T1  3  8  3  8
>
> >>> a.join(b, how='outer')
>       A    B    C    D
> T1  3.0  8.0  3.0  8.0
> T2  5.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
> T3  NaN  NaN  5.0  2.0
>
> >>> a.join(b, how='outer').loc[a.index ^ b.index]
>       A    B    C    D
> T2  5.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
> T3  NaN  NaN  5.0  2.0
>
> >>> a.join(b, how='outer').loc[a.index.symmetric_difference(b.index)]
>
>       A    B    C    D
> T2  5.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
> T3  NaN  NaN  5.0  2.0
> ```